# Displaying a User Tag with a UILabel and UIButton

Tags: ios, tags, uibutton, uilabel

In my app, I have a list of tags corresponding to a user that I would like to display. The tag should have a text field and a button on the right hand side to delete the tag (much like the tags on this site when asking a question!)

I only want part of the tag to be clickable, so I don't want to place a UILabel inside a UIButton, and it seems that adding a UIButton to a UILabel is bad practice. What is the best way to create this object? 
I want something similar to a UITableViewCell, but not a UITableViewCell because it won't be displayed in a table view.

Comment: Create a subclass of `UIView` with a `UILabel` and a `UIButton`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to create a `UIView` subclass, we could name it `TagView`, give `UILabel` and `UIButton` to display, and don't forget to create a delegate protocol to for action response.

Maybe it like this.

```
@protocol TagViewDelegate 
@optional
- (void)didSelectedTagView:(TagView *)tagView;
- (void)didTagViewAccessoryButtonTapped:(TagView *)tagView;
@end
@interface TagView : UIView
{
    UILabel *label;
    UIButton *accessoryButton;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) id delegate;
@property (readonly, nonatomic) UILabel *label;
@end
```

Then implement a `UITapGestureRecognizer` for label and touchUpInside event for button

```
- (void)initUIElement {
   // give it a gestureRecognizer for label to response the label did select
   UITapGestureRecognizer *labelTapGR = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSelectedLabel:)];
   [label addGestureRecognizer:labelTapGR];       

   [accessoryButton addTarget:self action:@selector(accessoryTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
}
```

in the method `didSelectedLabel:` and `accessoryTapped:` , give response to tagView's delegate like this.

```
- (void)didSelectedLabel:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    [self.delegate didSelectedTagView:self];
}

- (void)accessoryTapped:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate didTagViewAccessoryButtonTapped:self];
}
```

There is a library you may take a look.

- [DWTagList](https://github.com/domness/DWTagList)

Answer (score 0):

Just like cabellicar123 said, use a `UIView` and place your `UILabel` and `UIButton` inside it. You have a couple of ways to do this.

First, you can make a XIB file with the main view being your UIView, and just drag into it a `UIButton` and a `UILabel` and position them the way you want, and then in code load the nib when you need it.

Second is to create this `UIView` programmatically, and use the `addSubview` method and add your `UILabel` and `UIButton` that way. Make sure you have defined these two subviews with `initWithFrame` if you are using this method, so that they are correctly placed WITHIN the `UIView`. What I mean by this is that the origin of these views should be relative to the top left corner of the `UIView`.